# Declare env variable which value include space for docker/docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have an environment variable defined in a file passed in via `--env-file` like this:
`TEST_VAR=The value`

Does anybody know whether this is legal? should I place `"` around the value for this to be interpreted as needed in docker?
Thanks

**EDIT**: Quotation marks will not be a good solution as it is will be part of the val see reference [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Lets see the result running the following compose file:

```
version: "3"

services:
    service:
        image: alpine
        command: env
        env_file: env.conf
```

env.conf:

```
TEST_VAR1=The value
TEST_VAR2="The value2"
```

`docker-compose up` Result:

```
service_1 | PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
service_1  | TEST_VAR2="The value2"
service_1  | TEST_VAR1=The value
service_1  | HOME=/root
```

Therefore, it is legal to have spaces in the env value.

Comment: I meant values in docker env file, not docker-compose file
environment section

Comment: @JavaSa updated answer. The result is the same for both env_file and environment.

Comment: Ok, does this apply also to docker-compose2?

Comment: @JavaSa yes same result with compose version: "2"

Comment: What if I'm not using an env.conf? Do quotes still work in the yml file itself?

Comment: based on my experience @void.pointer, it doesn't work in the docker-compose.yml

Comment: Is there a solution for Docker run -e ? (without using an env file)

Answer (score 20):

You can escape the space with a `\`:

```
TEST_VAR=The\ value
```

**Edit**: This is how I pass them when starting the container (i.e. `docker run -e TEST_VAR=The\ value hello-world`). If you're using `docker-compose` or an env file, see [the answer by @yamenk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46141244/1941241).

Comment: This worked for me; so, I'm not sure what the other commentators are talking about! --  and the other answers are complete nonsense, and not related to `dockerfile`s.

Answer (score 5):

In Dockerfile use doublequotes, do not use singlequotes because they do not expand variables inside, excerp from passing buildargs/envs to dockerfile and into a python script below:

```
ARG HOST="welfare-dev testapi"
ENV HOST "${HOST}"
ARG SITENAME="Institusjon"
ENV SITENAME "${SITENAME}"
RUN cd ${TESTDIR}/sensiotools/sensiotools && cd test && \
  ./testapi-events.py --activate --sitename="${SITENAME}" --host="${HOST}" --dbcheck --debug --wait=0.5 && \
  ./testapi-events.py --deactivate --sitename="${SITENAME}" --host="${HOST}" --dbcheck --debug
```

Answer (score 0):

My case with docker-compose, if that can help. I couldn't make use of the suggestions in the other answers.

For a variable in volumes, I could use the `.env` file:

```
# .env
LOCAL_DIR=/local/path
```

while for a variable with spaces (for https://github.com/wolfcw/libfaketime in my case) I had to use command line: `FAKETIME_ARG="@2021-02-11 13:23:02" docker-compose up`.

The resulting docker-compose file (note the `${}` just for `LOCAL_DIR`) :

```
# docker-compose.yml
services:
  myservice:
    build:
      context: ./path/to/dir/of/Dockerfile
      args:
        - FAKETIME_ARG
    volumes:
      - ${LOCAL_DIR}:/path/in/container
```