# Docker environment variable with spaces

Tags: java, docker, jar, environment-variables

I need to run a docker image where I pass a bunch of jvm configurations to a jar file. I'm passing the configs via -e parameters as the example bellow.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:9-jre

COPY test.jar /

CMD java -jar -DinstallationDate=$INSTALLATION_DATE /test.jar
```

Run command:

```
docker run -e INSTALLATION_DATE="03.05.10.2019 15:00:00" space
```

The problem is that when I run this, it gives me the following error:

> Error: Unable to access jarfile 15:00:00

I tried running it with the json notation, like:

```
docker run -e ["INSTALLATION_DATE","03.05.10.2019 15:00:00"] space
```

It doesn't give me an error, but the parameter comes as an empty string.
I also tried to escape the space char with "\", but still didn't work.

Anyone knows how can I send this parameter to the jar execution inside the docker container? Is there another approach to this?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46141148/declare-env-variable-which-value-include-space-for-docker-docker-compose)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is likely occurring because the `CMD` in your `Dockerfile`:

```
CMD java -jar -DinstallationDate=$INSTALLATION_DATE /test.jar
```

...is subject to word splitting after the variable `$INSTALLATION_DATE` is expanded.  In order to turn off word splitting for that second argument to `java`, consider enclosing the variable in double quotes:

```
CMD java -jar -DinstallationDate="$INSTALLATION_DATE" /test.jar
```