# Multi word environment variable in Dockerfile

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, dockerfile

I have a very simple Node.js app that takes in a location as a command line argument (`const location = process.argv[2];`) and logs the weather of that location to the console. I'm trying to run it in a docker container just to get practice with docker.

Here is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

ENV location=San\ Diego

CMD ["sh", "-c", "node app.js ${location}"]
```

The problem is, I can't pass in an environment variable that is more than one word. For example, `San Diego` gets run as just `San`. This is the case with both the default environment variable in the Dockerfile and any environment variables I pass it when I run the image.

How can I make it so that I can pass in something like `Los Angeles` and have the app fetch the data for Los Angeles, for both the ENV variable in the Dockerfile, as well as any environment variable passed in as an arg when I run the image?

Comment: `ENV location="San Diego"` work?

Comment: @Geuis No, that doesn't work. I tried it.

Comment: Bit rusty on this, but I don't think you need to pass location in via `node app.js ${location}"`. You should be able to access the envvar in app.js via process.env

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Declare env variable which value include space for docker/docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46141148/declare-env-variable-which-value-include-space-for-docker-docker-compose)

Comment: @mikeb No. But @Geuis got me on the right track to find a workaround. I just added an if statement at the beginning of the app to check if ```process.env.location``` exists, then set location to that variable, otherwise, set location to ```process.argv[2]``` so that it can also run locally.

Answer (score 1):

In your shell command:

```
ENV location=San\ Diego
CMD ["sh", "-c", "node app.js ${location}"]
```

You're not quoting the variable expansion, so it ultimately runs

```
sh -c 'node app.js San Diego'
```

which expands to two words.  You need to quote that in your command.  (Conversely, you can ask Docker to supply the `sh -c` wrapper for you.)

```
ENV location=San\ Diego
CMD node app.js "$location"
```